# How to pass a row to an Excel (Visual Basic for Applications) custom function?

Tags: excel, vba, user-defined-functions

I need to create a custom function for someone else to use in Excel. I can read VB script just fine but I have not done any programming in Excel. To start, I'm hoping to get a shell going. How would I create a function that could be called in a cell as `=@MyFunction(ThisRow)` (or something like that to hide complexity) to do the following:

```
Function MyFunction(Row) 
    firstName = Row.FIRST_NAME // FIRST_NAME is the column label
    lastName = Row.LAST_NAME
    name = firstName + " " + lastName // just an example of an operation
    MyFunction = name // return value
End Function
```

Search online produced some examples where a range is passed into the function. Since this function would be used by someone else, I'd prefer to limit the argument to the current row. Again, above is only a shell to get the function going. Once I have that working, I can proceed with complex operations within the function.

Example:

```
A1  | B1     | C1
Mel | Gibson | @MyFunction(thisrow)

C1 would produce 'Mel Gibson'
```

Comment: `MyFunction(ByVal argRow as Range)`

Comment: @Harun24HR This is what my searches produced. Are you saying that Range is the Row? I understand a Range as a rectangle, not a line.

Comment: What do you mean by `Row`? Row means row number or reference cell?

Comment: Can you put a screenshot of your sample data?

Comment: Either would work, as long as I could read row cells in the function. Assuming A1 shows 'Harun' and B1 shows '24HR', I'd like to put =@MyFunction(ThisRow) in C1 to produce 'Harun24HR' in C1 where function is called. Again. this is just a shell. Actual logic will be very complex, so I need a custom function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very simple task that can easily be done using just a worksheet formula:

```
=CONCATENATE(A1," ",B1)
```

[image]

However, if you insist on using a UDF function, this should do

```
Public Function MyFunction() As String

    With Application.Caller
        MyFunction = .Parent.Cells(.Row, Range("FIRST_NAME").Column) & _
            " " & .Parent.Cells(.Row, Range("LAST_NAME").Column)
    End With

End Function
```

In the above, you won't even need to pass an argument. It uses the `Application.Caller.Row` method to grab the row from wherever the function is located in.

You would just use the function `=MyFunction()` and VBA will automatically determine the row the function is located in.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this Application.Caller worked out great. Again, my example was simple just to get the function going. I have placed much more code there. I had to create private functions and delegate some work to them, to keep things readable.

Answer (score 0):

I am not clear about your goal but this may help you.

```
Public Function MyFunction(ByVal argRow As Long)
Dim fName As String
Dim lName As String

    fName = Range("A" & argRow)
    lName = Range("B" & argRow)

MyFunction = fName & " " & lName
End Function
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Function MyFunction(ByVal rowIndex As Long)
    Dim firstNameCol As Long
    Dim lastNameCol As Long

    firstNameCol = Rows(1).Find(What:="FIRST_NAME", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole).Column
    lastNameCol = Rows(1).Find(What:="LAST_NAME", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole).Column

    MyFunction = Cells(rowIndex, firstNameCol).Value & " " & Cells(rowIndex, lastNameCol).Value
End Function
```